# Zend form: image as submit button

Tags: php, zend-framework, form-submit

Zend talk.I need two submit buttons in my Zend_form so that after populating or validating the form, I can check wich button was clicked using the isChecked() method.

- Since now I used the **Zend_Form_Element_Submit** but what if I want to use an Image as submit button?
- Using the **Zend_Form_Element_Image** is the right solution?Do I need to set its attribute "type=submit"?Would the is checked method still available on this element?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Zend_Form_Element_Image** is the correct element to use, the type will set to image automatically.
If you want to check if the button was clicked in your controller then simply use

`if (isset($this->_request->buttonname_x))`

or

`if (isset($this->_request->buttonname_y))`

as the browser will return the XY coordinates of the pointer on the image.

I hope this helps.

Kind regards

Garry